# Complement of Sum of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am able to prove that for an Operator $A$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ one has the following identity for the resolvent:
$$\varrho(A-\omega) = \rho(A)-\omega$$
However i want to have an identity for the spectrum of $A-\omega$. So i thought ok this could be 
$$\sigma(A-\omega) = \sigma(A)-\omega$$
But i am totally stuck proving this. It would suffice to know if someone told me if the statement is true.

More general: Let $M \subset \mathbb{C}, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and define the set
$$M-\alpha := \{ x = y - \alpha \colon y \in M \}$$
Does it hold that 
$$(M-\alpha)^c = M^c-\alpha$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. More generally, the complementation operation on subsets of a set $C$ commutes with any bijection from $C$ onto $C$.  (So you'll be using the fact that $z\mapsto z-\alpha$ is a bijection from $\mathbb C$ onto $\mathbb C$.)